# Why have I lost 15 reputation points on this answer?

Tags: support, reputation

I recently started participating in answering questions and helping other users for gaining a higher reputation. It looks like I lost 15 reputation points on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40700625/how-to-add-new-html-elements-inside-div-tag-on-basis-of-no-of-items-in-list/40700826#40700826) and I am trying to understand the reason so I don't repeat the same mistake again.

Can someone please clarify it?

Comment: question owner marked your answer as accepted  answer?

Comment: No, only commented that it worked for them

Comment: Well, they chose another answer as accepted. Maybe they had chosen yours for a moment and then reconsidered. That would explain the 15 point difference.

Comment: @Pekka웃 OP is mistaken. Their reputation history shows that their answer was accepted on November 21, then un-accepted today (November 25).

Answer (score 7):

That's because your answer was marked as **['Accepted answer'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** and then the author of OP has moved the mark from your answer to another post (that may be because the other post is more helpful for him) so you lost the 15 points of the mark automatically.

You could notice that in your activity section under the **[Reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5443071/junior-john?tab=reputation&sort=post)** :

[image]

Your answer was accepted in (Nov 21) and unaccepted today (Nov 25).